# How to find the week which secured highest sales using MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

This is my sample .csv file. How can I find the week that has the highest sale?

**train.csv:**

> Store,Dept,Date,Weekly_Sales,IsHoliday 
>   1,1,2010-02-05,24924.5,FALSE
>   1,1,2010-02-12,46039.49,TRUE
>   1,1,2010-02-19,41595.55,FALSE
>   1,1,2010-02-26,19403.54,FALSE
>   1,1,2010-03-05,21827.9,FALSE
>   1,1,2010-03-12,21043.39,FALSE
>   1,1,2010-03-19,22136.64,FALSE
>   1,1,2010-03-26,26229.21,FALSE
>   1,1,2010-04-02,57258.43,FALSE

Comment: It is better to show us that you have tried something that did not work as expected, or at least have an idea for a solution, before asking for the answer to a problem.

Comment: i tried in R ...but i want it using Mapreduce

Answer (score 0):

I will not provide the code for you, just give you the idea.

You can find the local maximum sales for each mapper and emit a `(sales,date)` pair. To do that, you can either use the cleanup method of the mapper, or use a combiner.

Using a single reducer `(setNumReduceTasks(1))`, you will get all the local maxima together in the reduce task. Keep the maximum sales in the reducer and emit the date value(s) for it.